# Can someone explain why the following DQL works?

Tags: orm, doctrine

```
$user = Doctrine_Core::getTable('User')
    ->createQuery('u')
    ->innerJoin('u.Profile p')
    ->where('p.username = ?', 'jwage')
    ->fetchOne();
```

It looks quite different from SQL which I'm quite used to,especially what does the `u` mean?

Can someone make it clear by a decent explanation?

Answer (score 1):

```
$q = Doctrine::getTable('User')->createQuery('u')->where('u.username = ?', 'JRL');
```

is a shorthand method for this:

```
$q = Doctrine_Query::create()->from('User u')->where('u.username = ?', 'JRL');
```

The `createQuery` method is declared as such: `createQuery($alias = '')`

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me like the `u` means the `User` table. It's just a short alias for it.